# How can I create a table using distinct values from a column as the column names for the new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with a Tag column with about 1000 distinct tags. I'd like to create a new table with a column for each distinct tag, the column name would be the tag value. Is there a nice and easy way to do this with T-SQL? Anything in SQL Server 2005 and up would be fine.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
Table:
Tag    Value    Timestamp
tag1   123      ---
tag1   456      ---
tag2   854      ---
tag3   923      ---
 .
 .
 .
tag90  324      ---

New Table:
tag1    tag2    tag3 ... tag90
123     854     923      324
456 ...
```

**Update:**

I'm aware of the limit (on the number of columns in a table), however the columns won't be sparse, and there will be no null or 0 values in any of the columns.

The reason I want this table is I'd like to run the SSAS clustering algorithm against the columns of this new table.

Comment: Why do you need to store the data in a table with 1000 columns?  If you need to display the data in that format, then you can PIVOT. Storing data in 1000's of columns is a bad idea.

Comment: You've concluded this is a bad idea before I've had a chance to answer your question?

Comment: My point is that there are ways to get the data into the format that you want without storing it in 1000 columns.

Comment: @SpaceghostAli there is almost no good reason whatsoever to store data in 1000 columns.

Comment: If you could give us what your overall goal is we could probably give you a solution that does not involve using that many columns.

Comment: @SpaceghostAli It's usually a bad idea, regardless of the answer to that question. Which, by the way, you haven't answered.

Comment: @ypercube sorry, I did actually, see my comments to Gordon Linoff's answer for the answer to the question. Put it there since his posts were actually helpful

Comment: OK, I've updated your question with the new info (it's good to add info - that is useful for answering the question - in the question and not in comments.) Not all people will be reading all the comments.

Comment: @ypercube thanks, I'm at the office now so I just didn't get around to tidying up the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `PIVOT` table operator, then use the `INTO` clause to create a new table from the pivoted columns. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtablename
FROM ( SELECT tag, value FROM tags) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  MIN(value)
  FOR tag in ([tag1], [tag2], [tag3], [tag4])
) AS p;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79575/1)

---

**However,** in your case, you have to use the dynamic sql to do this dynamically for any number of tags in your table, and not to list them manually. Like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(tag)
                      FROM tags
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
                 INTO newtablename
                 FROM ( SELECT tag, value FROM tags) AS t
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                   MIN(value)
                   FOR tag in ( ' + @cols + ' )
                 ) AS p';

execute(@query);
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f168/1)

This will create a brand new table with the name `newtablename` that looks like:

```
| TAG1 | TAG2 | TAG3 | TAG4 |
-----------------------------
|  123 |  854 |  923 |   44 |
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to add a `row_number() over(partition by tag order by value)` to the subquery otherwise you will only get one row per tag and there might be more than one value for each tag.

Comment: Took a quick stab at this approach and it seems like it might do the trick

Comment: +1 . . . I'm glad you undeleted this.  The original answer looked correct for what the OP asked.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum number of columns in a normal SQL Server table is 1,024 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

Your request is dangerously close to the limit. So, although it is technically possible, it is highly not recommended. [Mahmoud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589492/how-can-i-create-a-table-using-distinct-values-from-a-column-as-the-column-names/16589658#16589658) seems correct for this purpose.

You *can* investigate something called "wide tables" which contain "sparse columns", if most of the values are 0/NULL.

If you explain the reason why you want to do this pivot, then there might be other solutions to your problem.

I have great sympathy for wanting to do data analysis with data in SQL.  Here, generic options:

1. Import the data into SAS, SPSS, or R. These do not have arbitrarily limits on the number of columns.
2. Concatenate the values together into a single column, perhaps separated by a comma. It can then be readily brought into another tool.
3. Use a database that has a higher limit on the number of columns, such as Oracle or MySQL (still have lowish limits but a bit better).
4. Use a technique called vertical partitioning to put the columns in separate tables. Supported directly by databases such as Vertica. Can be implemented by other databases. However, you then have the problem of the maximum number of columns allowed in a query.

For your particular problem, I would strongly encourage you to investigate clustering algorithms. K-means probably isn't going to give very good results on such wide data. I don't know if SSAS supports EM clustering, which might be a bit better. You could try to transform the analysis into an association rule problem. But the serious approach would be to transform the data using principal components and do the clustering in a lower dimensional space.

Comment: I'm aware of the limit, however the columns won't be sparse there will be no null or 0 values in any of the columns. The columns will contain data from instruments on a DRI plant. I'd like to run the SSAS clustering algorithm against the columns of this new table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If this is a no go with SQL and SSAS (my choice because of familiarity), I think I'll explore some of the options you've listed here as well as Hadoop