# SQL SELECT based on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Im trying to generate the following output from a SQL 2008 query -

```
JobID | Repair & Reshape | Refit Stripped Parts | Polishing 
1000  | true             | true                 | false
1001  | true             | true                 | false
1002  | true             | true                 | false
1003  | true             | true                 | false
1004  | true             | true                 | false
```

The table structure I have is -

JobDetails

```
ID - PK Auto increment
JobID - Int (Joined to Jobs table)
PhaseID - String (joined to JobPhases table)
```

JobPhases

```
ID - PK String
Name - VarChar(150)
```

So far, I have -

```
SELECT JobID, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]
 FROM    
(   
    SELECT  JobID, PhaseID, [x] = 1 FROM    JobDetails  
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   SUM(x)
    FOR PhaseID IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) pvt
```

But not sure how I am going to replace 0-7 etc with the Job Phase names?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this you might get an idea of how to achieve it

[Distinct Row values as Columns Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470499/distinct-row-values-as-columns-sql-server)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(jobtype) 
                        from yourtable
                        group by jobtype
                        ORDER BY jobtype
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')
    --SELECT @cols
    set @query = 'SELECT  JobID,' + @cols + ' from 
                 (
                    select JobID, jobtype, jobvalue from yourtable
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    MAX(jobvalue)
                    for jobtype in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

    execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` that table with the table `JobPhases` in the anchor query, then use the phases names' list in the `FOR Name IN` and list the phases' names:

```
SELECT *
 FROM    
(   
    SELECT  j.JobID, j.PhaseID, p.Name, x
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases AS p ON p.ID = j.haseId
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   SUM(x)
    FOR Name IN ([phasename1], [phasename2], ...)
) pvt
```

Comment: This works, however is there a way to avoid manually typing out the phase names, but do it on a select based statement from the JobPhases table? Cheers

Comment: Yes, in this case you have to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL, for example see [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16589658/722783).